# Add CSS if host has (click)

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a library and I have a `<my-card>` component. It's a component that will often have a `(click)` handler on it.

What I'm looking to do is to add `cursor: pointer` automatically when the component has `(click)` attached to it.

So for example, `<my-card>` would have the default cursor, and `<my-card (click)="onClick()>` would apply `cursor: pointer` to the component element.

Any clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to change `(click)` to `click` then you could do this using CSS.

HTML:

```
<my-card>Look at me</my-card>
<my-card click="onClick()">Click me</my-card>
```

CSS:

```
my-card {
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
[click] {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The `[click]` part in the CSS references an attribute of an element. So, this will target any element you use with the `click` attribute. If you only want to target any `<my-card>` element with the `click` attribute then you would change your CSS to `my-card[click]`.

Here's a fiddle for you to reference: https://jsfiddle.net/8w9Lqxr4/1/

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way to do this is to use a directive, take a look at this example:

```
import { HostBinding, Directive } from '@angular/core'
@Directive({
   selector: '[myClick]'
})
class MyClickDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.mousepointer') private isClick: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  @HostListener('click') onMyElemClicked() {
    this.isClick =!this.isClick;
  }
}
```

I've not tested this example but this is the way you must investigate.